Cube not rotating correctly?
so I have a simple program which has a Game game -object, which then has an object CANVAS canvas extending JPanel and a logic object, both are implementing Runnable and are run with 2 threads from the game object.
Then, I have a POLYGON object, which can read a file. I have read a file which has data for a cube (points and lines-to-be-drawn numbers), as seen below:
s -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 =
s 1.0 -1.0 -1.0 =
s 1.0 1.0 -1.0 =
s -1.0 1.0 -1.0 =
s -1.0 -1.0 1.0 =
s 1.0 -1.0 1.0 =
s 1.0 1.0 1.0 =
s -1.0 1.0 1.0 =

f 0 1 2 3 = 
f 4 5 6 7 =
f 0 4 7 3 =
f 1 5 6 2 =
f 0 4 5 1 =
f 3 7 6 2 =

Which after the points (or SPOT -objects, which hold x, y and z values.) are brought up to size and stored in a separate array. I have tried printing out the values and they are as should.
On the update function of the polygon, I go through the points array and create a point from the sized up point, added together with the positioned point, resulting in a new point, which is then fed through the rotation function and stored in a separate array for painting.
this.rotation = this.rotation.Add(new SPOT(0.1, 0.1, 0.1));
for(int i = 0; i < this.point.length; i++){
    SPOT r = this.RotatePoint(this.scaled.Get(i).Add(this.positioned.Get(i)));
    // ^-- Rotation function returning point from size + position.
    this.painted.Position(r,i);    
}

Problem is, the cube doesn't seem to keep its form as a cube, like can be seen in the images below:


Another picture of the beginning of the draw, where the cube is in form (without perspective/projection):

My rotation function is, as I can't figure out where else the problem could be:
    public SPOT RotatePoint(SPOT g){
        double sx = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.rotation.x)), sy = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.rotation.y)), sz = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.rotation.z));
        double cx = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.rotation.x)), cy = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.rotation.y)), cz = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.rotation.z));
        SPOT spot = g;
        g.y = (cx * (spot.y - this.center.y) - sx * (spot.z - this.center.z)) + this.center.y;
        g.z = (sx * (spot.y - this.center.y) + cx * (spot.z - this.center.z)) + this.center.z;
        //spot = g;
        g.x = (cy * (spot.x - this.center.x) + sy * (spot.z - this.center.z)) + this.center.x;
        g.z = (sy * (spot.x - this.center.x) - cy * (spot.z - this.center.z)) + this.center.z;
        //spot = g;
        g.x = (cz * (spot.x - this.center.x) - sz * (spot.y - this.center.y)) + this.center.x;
        g.y = (cz * (spot.y - this.center.y) + sz * (spot.x - this.center.x)) + this.center.y;
        return g;
    }

If I try only x- or y-axis rotation (by commenting out the rest), the cube seems to rotate just fine, keeping its form.
I've tried following multiple examples and searched for hours for help, but seem to end up with the same result everytime, a distorted cube.
Any help would be much appreciated, and I'll provide more info if needed.
As requested a simple copypastable program, using the same coding as I have, same values and functions, just brought down to minimal. Somewhat reproducing the problem.
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
 
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
 
 
public class Main extends JPanel {
    
    public class LINE {
        public LINE () {
            this.slope = 0.0;
            this.start = 0.0;
            this.steps = 0.0;
            this.end = 0.0;
            this.rev = false;            
        }
        
        public double slope, start, steps, end;
        public boolean rev;
 
        public void Calc(Point3D from, Point3D to){
            Point3D a = from, b = to;
            double slope = 0.0, steps = 0.0, start = 0.0, end = 0.0;
            boolean rev = false;
            if(a.x != b.x) slope = (b.y - a.y) / (b.x - a.x);
 
            if(a.x != b.x && Math.abs(slope) <= 1.0){
                if(a.x > b.x){
                    a = to;
                    b = from;
                }
                start = a.x;
                end = b.x;
                steps = a.y - slope * a.x;
            } else {
                if(a.y > b.y){
                    a = to;
                    b = from;
                }            
                slope = (b.x - a.x) / (b.y - a.y);
                start = a.y;
                end = b.y;
                steps = a.x - slope * a.y;
                rev = true;
            }   
            this.slope = slope;
            this.end = end;
            this.start = start;
            this.rev = rev;
            this.steps = steps;
        }
    }
 
    static public class Point3D {
        public Point3D (double x, double y, double z) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.z = z;
        }
        public Point3D (int x, int y, int z) {
            this.x = (double)x;
            this.y = (double)y;
            this.z = (double)z;
        }
        public double x, y, z;
        
    }
 
    public Main () {
        
    }
 
    public static Point3D[] points = new Point3D[8], draw = new Point3D[8];
    public static int[][] lines = new int[6][4];
    public static Point3D center = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);
    public static Point3D rotation = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);
 
    public static void main(String[] args){
 
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Dimension size = new Dimension(640, 480);
        Main canvas = new Main();
        canvas.setPreferredSize(size);
        canvas.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(10, 10);
        frame.setTitle("Title");
        frame.setVisible(true);
 
        points[0] = new Point3D(100, 100, 100);
        points[1] = new Point3D(200, 100, 100);
        points[2] = new Point3D(200, 200, 100);
        points[3] = new Point3D(100, 200, 100);
        points[4] = new Point3D(100, 100, 200);
        points[5] = new Point3D(200, 100, 200);
        points[6] = new Point3D(200, 200, 200);
        points[7] = new Point3D(100, 200, 200);
        
        draw[0] = new Point3D(100, 100, 100);
        draw[1] = new Point3D(200, 100, 100);
        draw[2] = new Point3D(200, 200, 100);
        draw[3] = new Point3D(100, 200, 100);
        draw[4] = new Point3D(100, 100, 200);
        draw[5] = new Point3D(200, 100, 200);
        draw[6] = new Point3D(200, 200, 200);
        draw[7] = new Point3D(100, 200, 200);
 
        
        lines[0][0] = 0;
        lines[0][1] = 1;
        lines[0][2] = 2;
        lines[0][3] = 3;
 
        lines[1][0] = 4;
        lines[1][1] = 5;
        lines[1][2] = 6;
        lines[1][3] = 7;
 
        lines[2][0] = 0;
        lines[2][1] = 4;
        lines[2][2] = 7;
        lines[2][3] = 3;
 
        lines[3][0] = 1;
        lines[3][1] = 5;
        lines[3][2] = 6;
        lines[3][3] = 2;
 
        lines[4][0] = 0;
        lines[4][1] = 4;
        lines[4][2] = 5;
        lines[4][3] = 1;
 
        lines[5][0] = 3;
        lines[5][1] = 7;
        lines[5][2] = 6;
        lines[5][3] = 2;
        
 
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            center.x += points[i].x;
            center.y += points[i].y;
            center.z += points[i].z;
        }
        center.x /= 8;
        center.y /= 8;
        center.z /= 8;
 
        while(true){         
            RotatePoints();     
            canvas.repaint();
            try{
            Thread.sleep(16);
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(125, 23, 238));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 25, 25);
        LINE line = new LINE();
        for(int x = 0; x < 6; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
                int a = lines[x][y], b = lines[x][(y + 1) % 4];
                line.Calc(draw[a], draw[b]);
                for(; line.start < line.end; line.start += 1.0){
                    double w = line.slope * line.start + line.steps;
                    if(line.rev){
                        g.drawRect((int)w, (int)line.start, 1, 1);
                    } else {
                        g.drawRect((int)line.start, (int)w, 1, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 
    }
 
    public static void RotatePoints(){
        rotation.x += 0.1;
        rotation.y += 0.5;
        rotation.z += 0.25;
 
        double sx = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.x)), sy = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)), sz = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotation.z));
        double cx = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.x)), cy = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.y)), cz = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotation.z));
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            Point3D spot = points[i];
 
            draw[i].y = (cx * (spot.y - center.y) - sx * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.y;
            draw[i].z = (sx * (spot.y - center.y) + cx * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.z;
            spot = draw[i];// new Point3D(draw[i].x, draw[i].y, draw[i].z);
            draw[i].x = (cy * (spot.x - center.x) - sy * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.x;
            draw[i].z = (sy * (spot.x - center.x) + cy * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.z;
            spot = draw[i]; //new Point3D(draw[i].x, draw[i].y, draw[i].z);
            draw[i].x = (cz * (spot.x - center.x) - sz * (spot.y - center.y)) + center.x;
            draw[i].y = (cz * (spot.y - center.y) + sz * (spot.x - center.x)) + center.y;
 
        }    
    }
 
}

Working rotation function for the example:

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            Point3D spot = points[i];
            draw[i].y = (cx * (spot.y - center.y) - sx * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.y;
            draw[i].z = (sx * (spot.y - center.y) + cx * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.z;
            spot = new Point3D(points[i].x, draw[i].y, draw[i].z);
            draw[i].x = (cy * (spot.x - center.x) - sy * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.x;
            draw[i].z = (sy * (spot.x - center.x) + cy * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.z;
            spot = new Point3D(draw[i].x, draw[i].y, draw[i].z);
            draw[i].x = (cz * (spot.x - center.x) - sz * (spot.y - center.y)) + center.x;
            draw[i].y = (cz * (spot.y - center.y) + sz * (spot.x - center.x)) + center.y;
        }   


Your naming conventions could be better. Can you make a small complete example? What is your "rotation" it looks like you're using Euler angles? Ie rotation.x is rotation about the x axis, rotation.y is rotation about the y axis and rotation.z is rotation about the z axis? Why do you assign the rotation twice? Are you modifying spot? It looks really strange.

@matt Sorry, by small example you mean? What do you mean assigning twice? Spot is a custom class, holding x, y and z values.

A small complete example. Something we can compile and fix. In your function you have "this.pained.Get(index).x = ..." twice. Why are you re-assigning x twice. From the looks of it, this.painted.Get(index) should always return spot. So it is very confusing you're doing.

@matt Fair enough, I'll try to provide an example, it'll take a while since the program uses plenty of custom classes, i'll strip it down to bare bones. As for the assigining, that's from a followed example, or multiple examples. first around X axis, then around Y axis and lastly around Z axis. And yes, Get returns a spot. My apologies.

I don't mean a SPOT I mean you called SPOT spot = this.painted.Get(index); It seems like that is always going to return spot the same object. " first around X axis, then around Y axis and lastly around Z axis." right those are euler angles. You should make a function that takes, double[] rotate( double[] point, double[] angles, double[] center) or similar. Get the math right, then fix your classes.

@matt I made an example (link edited to the end of post), but there the problem seems different, cube seems to keep shape, but it gets smaller and smaller. Thanks for your input.

Please allow me to clarify what @matt requested in their second comment. You will want to create a small reproducible example, a [mre], one small enough to allow you to post the code as code-formatted text, in its entirety in your question itself, not in a link. You will want to add more text to 1) fully explain this runnable program, and 2) abide by the site's text to code requirements. The link will explain what this means. Note that no key information should require one of us going to a link but rather it is best for it to all be easily obtainable within the question itself.

I have copied and pasted your code for you into your question itself.

Understood, I tried explaining a bit more and going through the process. Not sure I can make a much smaller example, given the circumstances, hopefully it's alright.

Your problem is you're modifying the values while you perform the rotation. When you do points[i].y = ... then on the next line you do points[i].z = ... you're using the modified version of points[i].y to update points[i].z don't forget, points[i] is spot.

@matt Yeah, I realized that, I updated the code on the post, which now somewhat resembles the problem I'm having.

Managed to get a working cube rotation, and I think I know where I wen't wrong. I was playing around with the variables and what was going on (I think), was that I was overwriting existing values, instead of creating new values.
For example:
public void Function(SPOT givenValues) {
    SPOT toModify = givenValues;
    // do some modifications to toModify variable, effectively overwriting the original SPOTs values
}

Is not the same as:
public void Function(SPOT givenValues) {
    SPOT toModify = new SPOT(givenValues.x, givenValues.y, givenValues.z);
    // Do some modifications to toModify variable

}

A gif of the working rotation on the center point:

If anyone can verify, would be much appreciated.
My code working looks like so, after changes:
 public SPOT RotatePoint(SPOT g, SPOT center){
        double sx = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.rotation.x)), sy = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.rotation.y)), sz = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(this.rotation.z));
        double cx = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.rotation.x)), cy = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.rotation.y)), cz = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(this.rotation.z));
        SPOT r = new SPOT(g.x, g.y, g.z);
        SPOT spot = g;
        r.y = (cx * (spot.y - center.y) - sx * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.y;
        r.z = (sx * (spot.y - center.y) + cx * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.z;
        spot = new SPOT(r.x, r.y, r.z);
        r.x = (cy * (spot.x - center.x) - sy * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.x;
        r.z = (sy * (spot.x - center.x) + cy * (spot.z - center.z)) + center.z;
        spot = new SPOT(r.x, r.y, r.z);
        r.x = (cz * (spot.x - center.x) - sz * (spot.y - center.y)) + center.x;
        r.y = (cz * (spot.y - center.y) + sz * (spot.x - center.x)) + center.y;
        return r;
    }


Here is a version of the rotate that is a complete isolated example. You can use it to get the math correct, and then use it in your program. It is a framework for testing. You know what the output should be, and there might be some rounding error.
public class RotatePoints{
    static record Vec3(double x, double y, double z){};
    
    static Vec3 rotate( Vec3 angles, Vec3 center, Vec3 point){
        double sx = Math.sin(angles.x);
        double cx = Math.cos(angles.x);
        double sy = Math.sin(angles.y);
        double cy = Math.cos(angles.y);
        double sz = Math.sin(angles.z);
        double cz = Math.cos(angles.z);
        
        double dy = point.y - center.y;
        double dz = point.z - center.z;
        
        double y1 = cx*dy - cx*dz + center.y;
        double z1 = sx*dy + cx*dz + center.z;
        
        double dx = point.x - center.x;
        dz = z1 - center.z;
        
        double x1 = cy*dx + sy*dz + center.x;
        z1 = -sy*dx + cy*dz + center.z; 
        
        dx = x1 - center.x;
        dy = y1 - center.y;
        
        x1 = cz*dx - sz*dy + center.x;
        y1 = sz*dx + cz*dy + center.y;
        
        return new Vec3(x1, y1, z1);
        
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Vec3 center = new Vec3(0, 0, 0);
        Vec3 point = new Vec3(1, 0, 0);
        Vec3 angles = new Vec3(0, 0, Math.PI);
        Vec3 out = rotate( angles, center, point);
        //rotate x=1 about the z axis pi degrees should be x=-1.
        System.out.println( out.x + ", " + out.y + ", " + out.z);
    }

}

This is what you should try to do with your code. Make something small and concise that you can verify your problem with. Then write a test. note I haven't made sure all of the signs are correct on the rotation.
